# Excel VBA how to compare an array of worksheet names to open worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

Forgive me if this is a noob question but I have spent hours crawling this site for an answer.

I am trying to write a macro that will loop through all of my worksheets and delete all that are not in a pre-defined array.  However I am having difficulty comparing the worksheet names in the array to the actual names in the workbook. Here is my code:

```
    Dim DoNotDelete(10) As Worksheet
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim dnd As Worksheet


    Set DoNotDelete(0) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Home")
    Set DoNotDelete(1) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Global Statistics")
    Set DoNotDelete(2) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
    Set DoNotDelete(3) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Project Dependencies")
    Set DoNotDelete(4) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Completed Projects")
    Set DoNotDelete(5) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Risk Overview- Yellow")
    Set DoNotDelete(6) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Issue Overview- Red")
    Set DoNotDelete(7) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Issue Overview- Red")
    Set DoNotDelete(8) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dependencies")
    Set DoNotDelete(9) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Completed Data")
    Set DoNotDelete(10) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

    For Each sh In Worksheets
        Delete = False
        For Each dnd In DoNotDelete
            If dnd = sh Then
                Delete = False
                Exit For
            Else
                Delete = True
            End If
        Next dnd

        If Delete = True Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sh).Delete
        End If

    Next sh
```

It errors out every time at:

```
If dnd = sh then
```

I am using Excel 2007 (dont ask...). Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is the error that it gives?

Answer (score 4):

You have to check reference equality with the is keyword

```
If dnd is sh Then
    Delete = False
    Exit For
Else
    Delete = True
End If
```

Another way, compare an identifying or unique property:

```
If dnd.Name = sh.Name Then
    Delete = False
    Exit For
Else
    Delete = True
End If
```

Comment: Good call using the `Is` keyword.

Comment: @BenBlack thanks!  We were both on the same page for using the name.  The =,is difference has gotten me in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
If dnd.Name = sh.Name Then
    -- stuff here
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Explainations in the comments

```
Sub DeleteWorksheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet 'Used to loop through all worksheets in workbook
Dim ArrayElement As Variant 'Used to loop through all elements in the array
Dim DoNotDelete(0 To 10) As String 'Used to store NAMES of worksheets rather than objects
Dim Found As Boolean 'Used to test whether or not the worksheet in found in the array

'Store values as strings
DoNotDelete(0) = "Home"
DoNotDelete(1) = "Global Statistics"
DoNotDelete(2) = "Summary"
DoNotDelete(3) = "Project Dependencies"
DoNotDelete(4) = "Completed Projects"
DoNotDelete(5) = "Risk Overview- Yellow"
DoNotDelete(6) = "Issue Overview- Red"
DoNotDelete(7) = "Issue Overview- Red"
DoNotDelete(8) = "Dependencies"
DoNotDelete(9) = "Completed Data"
DoNotDelete(10) = "Data"

For Each ws In Worksheets 'For every worksheet in this workbook
    Found = False 'Reset Found value to false
    For Each ArrayElement In DoNotDelete 'Check if worksheet name is found in array
        If ws.Name = ArrayElement Then 'If it is, set Found to true and exit the loop
            Found = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ArrayElement
    If Found = False Then 'If worksheet name isn't in the array, delete it
        ws.Delete
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```